# how to limit view to just show each type one time?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, content-type

I have a content type what is **news**, the news has a field type that is **List (text)** *to keep different types of news*. for example I have Health, Sport, Economic and etc.

So now I am going to create a block and have each of these type in that as a hyperlink.

I can do it and I created a new view block but each **news_type** may showing more than one time according to published content.

How to set the view (for block) to just show **news_types** and show them just one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by following the steps given below:

1. Enable aggregation under Advanced Accordion of the view
2. Add Nid field & set aggregation type as Count Distinct
3. Exclude Nid field from display
4. Add news type field & set Aggregation type as Group results together, in Group Column select Value option from dropdown
5. Remove Publishing Date from sort criteria

Please check attached screenshot for reference

[image]

You can check [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-causing-from-random-sort?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more information, and maybe help you.

Comment: I know this answer and it is here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151076/how-to-limit-view-to-just-show-each-type-one-time/151079#151079 I need other answer